# When is the cut locus a finite tree?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbf{R}^2$ be a bounded, simply connected domain, with a regular boundary, say of class $C^2$ at least. Let the *cut locus* $C$ of $\Omega$ be the set of points $x \in \Omega$ for which there exist two or more points $z_1,z_2 \in \partial \Omega$ for which
\begin{equation}
\lvert x - z_i \rvert = \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega).
\end{equation}

It is claimed in a paper of [Panov and Petrunin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6856) that *an arbitrarily small perturbation of the boundary guarantees that the cut locus $C$ is a finite graph, embedded inside $\Omega$*. (In fact, once the graph structure of $C$ is established one can show that $C$ is a tree.) They attribute this fact to [Ionin and Pestov](https://mathscinet-ams-org.libproxy.ucl.ac.uk/mathscinet-getitem?mr=107214), but unfortunately this is available only in Russian.

**Question.** How does this perturbation argument go? (And for which 'pathological' domains is it necessary in the first place?)

Comment: Not sure, but there may be relevant citations in this paper: Itoh, Jin-ichi, and Costin Vîlcu. "Every graph is a cut locus." *Journal of the Mathematical Society of Japan* 67, no. 3 (2015): 1227-1238. [arXiv abs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1759).

Comment: Possibly this is wrong, but: Isn't the cut locus a finite graph if the curve $\gamma$ is piecewise linear, and can't this be arranged after an arbitrarily small perturbation?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thank you for this, some of the references could be relevant, although I didn't see any that look directly applicable.

Comment: Both authors are on MO -- perhaps either DmitriPanov or @AntonPetrunin will comment!

Comment: @MattF. That's a fortuitous coincidence - I would certainly welcome their input!

Comment: @user142382 I should have specified that the perturbation in question ought to be in the smooth category: the perturbed curve should remain regular, which excludes the piecewise linear curves that you suggest.

Comment: The pathological smooth shapes (relative to cut loci) are those with constant curvature, which is everywhere destroyed by generic perturbations. But the pathological continuous curves are much wilder, e.g. sin(1/x) graphs, and i avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

Edited Jan31, 2022: the cut locus of the curve $\gamma$ is a finite tree if the boundary is smooth and if the curve bounds a contractible domain, i.e. $\Omega \approx \{pt\}$. This follows from Blum's MAT and the basic ideas of the theory. The observation about $C$ being a *locally finite* tree requires the boundary be smooth or $C^1$. In this case the ``branches" of the tree cannot accumulate, and the principle curvatures of the boundary hypersurface are bounded. Otherwise if the boundary is only $C^0$, then the cut locus $C$ might be a tree with infinite degree vertices.

N.B. It does not really make sense to speak of trees in this category, so terms like "branches" and "tree" are equally informal.

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open subset. The cut locus $C$ of $A$ is defined as the domain of nondifferentiability of $dist_{\partial A}: A\to \mathbb{R}$.

Blum's Medial Axis Transform (MAT) is the set $$M(A):=\{x\in A ~|~  card|argmin_{y\in \partial A} dist(x,y)|\geq 2\}.$$

We find $M(A) \subset C$, although $M(A)$ is not always closed, with $\overline{M(A)}=C$.

(1) To answer the question posed in the OP's title: Both the cut locus $C$ and $M(A)$ have the homotopy type of the domain $A$, so if $A$ (or $\Omega$ in the notation of the OP) is contractible, then $C$ and $M(A)$ is contractible.

(2) To answer the OPs specific question about pathologies in $C$ and $M(A)$: the cut locus $C$ branches wherever the principal curvatures of the boundary $\partial A$ are positive (convex) with respect to the interior $A$. Saul Rodrigues Martin gives interesting example in [Is the max-centre map continuous for open bounded domains?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413480/is-the-max-centre-map-continuous-for-open-bounded-domains)

My original answer to the OP was not satisfactory. But essentially I would argue that the cut locus, if interpreted as a type of tree graph, has finitely many graph-edges if the boundary $\gamma$ is basically $C^1$. But once you have infinitely many edges, it's possible to get those edges to accumulate or to share a common intersection, i.e. a vertex of infinite degree.

Comment: Would you mind adding some information? I am still unsure about some details. Why is the cut locus locally a finite graph? What sort of deformations will in- or decrease the number of edges? What do you mean by 'branches' of $C$? I am confused about your last paragraph. When you say that the 'intersection with a disc is finite', presumably you mean that it has finitely many connected components; wouldn't that always be the case for a regular curve? In short, I still don't see what deformations will guarantee that the cut locus is a finite graph, and for which 'pathological' curves this fails.

Comment: @Leo Moos. Yes i will elaborate my above answer. But briefly, if the cut locus had a point ("vertex") which had infinite "degree", then the maximal disk centred at that point would intersect the boundary at infinitely many points, and then we'd conclude the boundary would consist of circular arcs (quarter circles, etc.). But this leads to contradiction because the cut locus of circular arcs are points, not edges.  Maybe thats still not clear....

Comment: I still don't understand why the degree of the vertices needs to be finite. One could imagine a region which is tangent to a disk at infinitely many points, but which has no circular arcs. The intersections will have an accumulation point, but it seems that the case of regular polygons is very special.

Comment: @Gabe K. Maybe the correct argument is simply this: $C$ is compact when $A$ is open and bounded. QED. There are no accumulation points.

Comment: But compactness won't rule out something like a curve which is piece-wise linear and touches the unit disk at angles $\theta/ n$. Now that might not be enough on it's own to make the cut locus at the origin have infinite degree, but it seems like you could modify the construction to make that happen.

Comment: @GabeK You're correct that any infinite-sided polygon inscribed in unit disk has cut loci and medial axes with infinitely many branches. Indeed $M(A)$ intersects the boundary at points with divergent curvature (the corners). I'm claiming that the infinite branches do not have a common intersection except when they are located on a spherical arc and focus to a common point. You're correct this deserves to be clarified.

Comment: By the phrase "the infinite branches do not have a common intersection" i mean the "graph-edges" containing the corners do not share a common "vertex".

Comment: Do you have some references for  this work by Blum?